# Accessing Data of a Theano Shared Variable

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, computer-vision, theano, mnist

I'v successfully loaded the MNIST dataset into Theano shared variables as follows

```
# Read MNIST dataset from gzipped file as binary
f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
# Store dataset into variable
train_set = cPickle.load(f)
# Close zipped file
f.close()
# Store data in Theano shared variable
train_set_x = theano.shared(numpy.asarray(train_set, dtype=theano.config.floatX)) # Data
train_set_y = theano.shared(numpy.asarray(train_set, dtype=theano.config.floatX)) # Labels
# Cast labels into int
train_set_y = theano.tensor.cast(train_set_y, 'int32')
```

My question is how do I access the data in both train_set_x and train_set_y. Each image in the data set is 28 * 28 pixels. That is a vector of length 784 with all elements in the vector as floats representing values between 0.0 and 1.0 inclusive. The labels are casted into int because it represents the label associated to each vector image and is a value between 0 and 9. I want to be able to loop over the train_set_x matrix images and train_set_y labels to view the data of each image and its label separately and eventually plot the images on screen.

Answer (score 3):

First, `train_set_x` and `train_set_y` *(before the cast)* and `train_set` are separate copy of the same train set. So I suppose you simplified your example too much, as you say that `train_set_x` is the input and `train_set_y` is the corresponding label and this don't make sense with the code.

The answer of you question depend of the contain of `mnist.pkl.gz`. Where did you get it? From the Deep Learning Tutorial? For my answer, I'll suppose `train_set` is a 2d numpy `ndarray`. So that you use a different `mnist.pkl.gz` file then the one from DLT.

With that supposition, you can call `train_set_x.get_value()` and this will return a copy of the `ndarray` in shared variable. If you don't want a copy, you can do `train_set_x.get_value(borrow=True)` and this will work. If the shared variable is on the GPU, this will copy the data from the GPU to the CPU, but it won't copy the data if it is already on the CPU.

`train_set_y` is a **Theano graph**, not a **Theano shared variable**. So you can't call `get_value()` on it. You need to compile and run the graph that give `train_set_y`. If you want to evaluate it only once, you can call `train_set_y.eval()` as a shortcut to compile and run it as it do not take any input except shared variable.

So you can do this:

```
for x,y in zip(train_set_x.get_value(), train_set_y.eval()):
   print x, y
```

Comment: Yes! I did get the mnist.pkl.gz from the DeepLearningTutorial. The pickled file represents a tuple of 3 lists : the training set, the validation set and the testing set. Each of the three lists is a pair formed from a list of images and a list of class labels for each of the images. An image is represented as numpy 1-dimensional array of 784 (28 x 28) float values between 0 and 1 (0 stands for black, 1 for white). The labels are numbers between 0 and 9 indicating which digit the image represents.

Comment: You're right! all the variables are copies of the same origianl train_set. Accoriding to the tutorial I can separate the data using an index. I have also tried to run train_set_x.get_value(borrow=True) and got and got an 2D array of zeros. when I try to evaluate train_set_y.eval() I get AttributeError: 'TensorVariable' object has no attribute 'eval'

Comment: @moeabdol That error is due that your Theano version if too old. Update to Theano 0.6rc3

Answer (score 1):

@Nouiz has pointed out the right way to show the values of both train_set_x and train_set_y. The problem was related to the environment variable "DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH" which was not setup.
I have a couple of python installations on my mac machine. An installation that was there as part of XCode. Another one which I have installed from python.org and a third installation which I installed from anaconda. Internally only the anaconda' python was able to run native c code for theano. My problem was due to me using the other python installations.
The way I fixed this was by editing the some lines in .bash_profile in my home directory. I pointed the default version to be the one I installed with anaconda and also set the environment variable DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/Users/Me/anaconda/lib". This solved the problem and everything works like a charm.